# Problem about $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f'(x) = l $ implies $f'(c) = l$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I found this problem in a paper.

> Let $f$ be a function differentiable on $(a, b)$ except possibly at $c
> \in (a, b)$. Suppose that $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f'(x) = l \in \Bbb
>  R$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f'(c) = l$.

But I think I have a counterexample for why the claimed result need not hold. Define,

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x + 1  & \text{if $-1\lt x \lt $ 0 } \\
x & \text{if $ \; 0 \le x \lt 1$}
\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is differentiable at each point of $(-1, 1) \setminus \{0\}$ with $f'(t) = 1$ for each non-zero point $t$ in the interval $(-1,1)$. And this also tells us that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f'(x) = 1$. But $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ since $f$ is not continuous there.

> Where am I going wrong?

P. S. : I found a similar problem in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis which has the additional stipulation that $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$ which can be used to apply the Mean Value Theorem to prove what is asked.

Comment: You are right, the function is supposed to be continuous on $(a,b)$, otherwise it is not true.

Comment: Although you are right, the statement is intended to provide a sufficient condition for differentiability. Since continuity is necessary for differentiability, the author of that paper probably understood it...

Comment: @Siminore: I initially thought I had to prove that the given information forced continuity at $c$ which obviously is wrong. And when I mean paper, I mean question paper. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @N.S.: Guess that settles it. Cheers,

Comment: Hello, given that you solved completely your problem I encourage you to add your own answer, to keep what you've learned somewhere, make it useful for others and keep this out from the unanswered queue :-)